# How can i handle file download in Codeigniter in pdf format?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

My requirement is that, there is one (download) link in my view page, and when i click on that view page, a summary of details, that i already uploaded during registration time  have to download it  in pdf format.

Comment: Try to use `$this->load->helper('download'); force_download($file_path, NULL);`

Comment: What does this second argument,NULL indicates

Comment: Answer of @Kavvson Empcraft is the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html)

> ```
> force_download([$filename = ''[, $data = ''[, $set_mime = FALSE]]])
> ```
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - $filename (string)
> - $data (mixed)
> - $set_mime (bool) – Whether to try to send the actual MIME type
>
> **Return type:**   void
>
> Generates server headers which force data to be downloaded to your
> desktop. Useful with file downloads. The first parameter is the name
> you want the downloaded file to be named, the second parameter is the
> file data.
>
> If you set the second parameter to NULL and $filename is an existing,
> readable file path, then its content will be read instead.
>
> If you set the third parameter to boolean TRUE, then the actual file
> MIME type (based on the filename extension) will be sent, so that if
> your browser has a handler for that type - it can use it.

**General Usage**

```
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download('/path/to/pdf.pdf', NULL);
```

**Case specific usage - Place in controller**

```
function file_download()
    {
        $file_name= $this->input->get('file_name');

        $this->load->helper('download');
        $data = file_get_contents($file_name);
        $name = 'My_new_name.pdf'; // custom file name for your download

        force_download($name, $data);
        //force_download($file_name, NULL); will get the file name for you
}
```

**HTML**
Let's say you have such link for your download

```
<a class="downloadable" href="/Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.pdf">
    /Resumes/Resumes1271354404687.pdf
</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
  $('.downloadable').click(function(){
  
     window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('CONTROLLER_NAME/file_download') ?>?file_name="+ $(this).attr('href');
  });
});
```