# Saving PDF file as "data" - using PHP MPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

IM trying to save a PDF file, generated from HTML, into the user's local using MPDF. Here is the part of the code responsable for this:

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $html = $this->load->view('gestao/relatorios/relatorio_cargo_cidades', $data, true);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->SetFooter(relatorio_footer());
    $mpdf->Output('relatorio_cargos_cidades_seletivo_' . $seletivo_id .'_'.date("Ymd_his").'.pdf', 'D');
```

At first I was trying to show the PDF using the **"I"** param from the **output** function, than the user could just see the PDF and choose to download it or not. But when I tried to submit a file into another website, it says that the file is not a PDF. Than I used my linux to see if the file was actually a PDF, here's what I got:

[image]

As you can see, the file is being saved as "data" for some reason. I've already tried to use the **'F'** param, also from the output function, and than it worked, I saved as PDF. But the **F** param only save the file inside the code folder, so it was not very usefull for me.

Can anyone tell me how could I save the file as an actually PDF using MPDF?

### EDIT

I think that the problem is being caused by CODEIGNITER, not by the MPDF. When I'm setting the last param from the **load->view** as **TRUE**, the returned HTML is in a data (string) form, and MPDF is not converting this properly.

Comment: You need to pass the path you want the file get saved with the `F` parameter. Not just the filename. `$mpdf -> Output ('save_file_to_path', 'F');`

Comment: @WayneOS But I want to save the file on the user's local machine, so I cannot specify the path or use the F param

Comment: If you want the user to get a direkt download you just need to user the `I` parameter and then set the right header. I can write your an answer for that

Comment: @wayneOS I would appreciate a lot

Comment: Hey, have you tried to add this `$mpdf->debug = true;` to force show the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ob_clean()` might solve your problem:

```
 ob_clean();
 $mpdf->Output('relatorio_cargos_cidades_seletivo_' . $seletivo_id .'_'.date("Ymd_his").'.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you SO MUCH <3 Can I understand what happened??

Comment: I know how frustrating it is when everything seems ok but still not working. Glad it helped, your welcome! It seems like before creating the pdf there is some data stored in buffer, therefore is unable to create output file, so you need to discard the content of the buffer.

Comment: ooooh, now I got it. Dude, I was really nervous when I felt like I was not able to fix it. You REALLY helped me and literally made my day. Thank you so much -  Heroes dont wear capes, they answer people on stack overflow

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use the `D` parameter for downloading:

```
$mpdf -> Output ('FILENAME.pdf', 'D');
```

or generate your own header and then output the content as string:

```
header ("Content-type: application/pdf");
header ("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=FILENAME.pdf");

$mpdf -> Output ('', 'S');
```

Comment: I discovered that the problem is not being caused by MPDF. Please, checkout my EDIT

Comment: Mhh, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528650/how-can-i-handle-file-download-in-codeigniter-in-pdf-format) will help you.